# update side drawer's picture once i changed in profile screen - react native

Tags: react-native

Side drawer component,

```
const photo = useSelector((state) => state.auth.photo);
    <View style={styles.avatar}>
          <Avatar
            size="large"
            rounded
            large
            source={{
              uri: photo,
            }}
          />
        </View>
```

In Profile Screen,

```
const photo = useSelector((state) => state.auth.photo);
 return (
     <View style={styles.avatarSection}>
        <componentA photo={photo} name={name} />
     </View>
);
```

Is it possible once i changed the profile picture in profile screen, it will reflect in side drawer right away?

Comment: is photo variable a URL? Does this URL change when you change the picture?

Comment: yes, Its a URL, and it will change once i updated the new image

Comment: URL is fetching from the server. API call. I am fetching the URL from the server and storing it to the redux state and using in both the component,

Comment: I can see the updated picture if i refresh the app or restart it or logged in again. i cant work out getting it once i uploaded in profile screen. pls help

Comment: It actually should work this way. I would suggest you to check carefully if redux state for photo URL is changing. Also can you share your reducer?

Comment: how should i share? in comment itself? its says its too long

Comment: you can edit your answer.

Comment: it worked. :D thank you

Comment: you are welcome.